# Google-maps-api is not loaded at all in android app

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, android-activity, google-maps-api-3

I have an android app with a Google Maps activity, the debug version works awesome, but the relase version don't load at all the map. The activity is launched, but the map is not showed.

This is the SS of the Google Maps Activity of the relase version:
[image]

Somebody know what's wrong?

This is activity xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.renovaciontabasco.gouapp.UbiActivity" />
```

the google_maps_api.xml:

```
 <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">YOUR_KEY_HERE</string>
```

And the java file:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.UiSettings;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class UbiActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    static double longitud;
    static double latitud;

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ubi);
       // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.

        int status= GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
        if(status== ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        } else {
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status,(Activity)getApplicationContext(),10);
            dialog.show();
        }

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

   public static void direccion(double longi, double lat){
       longitud = longi;
       latitud = lat;
   }

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
   public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
       mMap = googleMap;

       mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

       UiSettings uiSettings = mMap.getUiSettings();
       uiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
       LatLng locUniv = new LatLng(latitud,longitud);
       mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(locUniv).title("Universidad"));
       float zoomlevel = 16;
       mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(locUniv,zoomlevel));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in `java` file but in app settings with google services

If you are using firebase try to add sha1 sum of your release keystore

Also look at logs there must be information

**EDIT**

Also check in https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=...

That you have setup Android client in `OAuth 2.0 customer IDs`

e.g.

[image]